# Why am I getting different statistical outputs than my partner using the same code?

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a classification tree to the OJ dataset using the ISLR2 textbook. The response variable is "Purchase" which takes one of two values: "MM" or "CH".

```
library(ISLR2)
library(tree)
# (a) Create a training set containing a random sample of 800 obs
# and a test set containing the remaining observations. 
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(1:nrow(OJ), 800)
# (b) Fit a regression tree to the training set. Plot the tree, and 
# calculate the test MSE.
OJ.test <- OJ[-train, ]
tree.oj <- tree(Purchase~., OJ, subset = train) ##Produces error "NAs introduced by coercion"
plot(tree.oj) ##Produces error "Cannot plot singlenode tree"
```

My question is, does something seem wrong with my code or could I have an issue with R studios on my computer? I have the same code as my class partner and she can run the code fine. We also had the same code for our last assignment, but when I ran the code I produced different statistics in repeated runs. This has happened a few other times and it leads me to believe there's an issue with my computer and R, rather than the code. Any suggestions on where to start to resolve this?

Comment: I ran your code and did not get any errors. Perhaps try checking for updates of your packages?

Comment: Did you make sure both of you're using the same random seed `set.seed(...)`? Otherwise you'll be e. g. creating different training sets with `sample()`.

Comment: First thing to do, if you haven't already, is to start a **clean** R session [make sure you don't see anything about "previous workspace reloaded"] and see if it still happens. Second, from that clean run, post the results of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: What's in the object `OJ`? Do you both have the same content in `OJ`? How was it made or collected?